# Behavior difference between TIMESTAMP_DIFF and TIMESTAMP_SUB in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I tested two ways of finding if the difference between two events expires a given threshold and found out that the second one (using `TIMESTAMP_DIFF`) seems to be more consistent.

`TIMESTAMP_SUB(finished_at, INTERVAL 24 HOUR) < created_at`

`TIMESTAMP_DIFF(finished_at, created_at, HOUR) > 24`

But I don't understand why `TIMESTAMP_SUB` doesn't give the same result.

Answer (score 3):

`TIMESTAMP_SUB()` will subtract the *exact* amount of time units.  `TIMESTAMP_DIFF()` will return the whole amount of time units requested.  So a '23 hour and 55 minute' difference will return a `TIMESTAMP_DIFF()` of 23 hours.  See below:

```
with data as (
    select 
        cast('2021-11-29 20:40:40.010832 UTC' as timestamp) as created_at,
        cast('2021-11-30 20:35:40.010832 UTC' as timestamp) as finished_at
        --cast('2021-11-30 20:45:40.010832 UTC' as timestamp) as finished_at
)
select
    created_at,
    finished_at,
    timestamp_sub(finished_at, interval 24 hour) as finished_sub24,
    timestamp_sub(finished_at, interval 24 hour) >= created_at as finished_sub24_gt_created,
    timestamp_diff(finished_at, created_at, hour) as finished_created_diff_hours
from data
```

Switch the `finished_at` timestamps to show how it behaves with a '24 hour and 05' minute difference.

If you need more fidelity, you might consider using 24 * 60 minutes or 24 * 60 * 60 seconds.